Electrical Two body problem

Depicted above is the instance of a spherical shell, at which a point on that shell is negatively charged. Imagine that this shell is fixed by a hinge at the center, at an arbitrary point in space, so that it may rotate. Inside of that shell is positively charged hydrogen gas. How would, if at all, relevant to the problem, I formulate a Two Body Lagrangian solution?

is this a trick question? ... how would the shell rotate when it is fixed?

why doesn't the red ball just go straight to the blue thing (which isn't depicted as a point).

The red ball is attracted to the blue thing, and the blue thing is attracted to the red ball. The red ball isn't attached to anything. The blue thing represents negatively charged area of that shell. Because they are attracted to each other, the red ball derives linear energy, and the blue thing, which is attracted to the red ball derives rotational energy of the entire shell.

Use an x,y coordinate system and track blue over time assuming some rate of rotation. Then come up with forces on red based on blue's position.
